# broadcast receiver not working and app got force close

Tags: android

hi i want to ask that i use a broadcast receiver for incoming sms. but sometimes it is working and sometimes not. and because of this my app got force close. 
why my app got force close and is there any solution for this?
and is there any solution if receiver not start?

Comment: Can you give more detail, like posting your codes etc?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "force close".

Comment: ok.i m going to try this. thanks for this both of you

Comment: Can you please add more details..??